# How to cancel goroutines spawned from user spamming refresh on page, cancel the oldest goroutines if a newer one exists

Tags: go, asynchronous, concurrency, goroutine

Imagine a user doing this and hitting refresh, which triggers requests to be sent to my service:

[image]

If a user mashes refresh, I have a rate limiter to protect my database for being spammed, but I would rather cancel the earliest spawned routines from that user, instead of processing their batches sequentially

As an example, I have a dashboard with 6 charts, each chart is a db call

If the user hits refresh 10 times, that's 60 routines spawned. I could cancel any that haven't completed on the last refresh

**What I want to do, is if a request comes in, then cancel a previous identical request for that user**

In my code I have a routine that listens on a NATS subject for messages published on its subject

When a new request comes in, the request is added to the channel

I have a routine receiving on that channel

That routine spawns a routine for each db call. 1 request = 1 db call

How do I terminate the previous routines where the Userid and DbQueryToRun are the same

Here's my full code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
)

var (
    natsURL = "localhost:4242"
    subject = "listen.to.refresher"
    sub     *nats.Subscription
)

type NewRequest struct {
    Requestid    string `json: "requestid"`
    DbQueryToRun string `json: "dbQueryToRun"`
    Userid       int    `json: "userid"`
    RefreshCount int    `json: "refreshCount"`
}

func main() {

    nc, err := nats.Connect(natsURL)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    requests := make(chan NewRequest)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    sub, err = nc.QueueSubscribe(subject, subject, func(msg *nats.Msg) { // here is where requests come in
        wg.Add(1)
        var nr NewRequest
        err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, &nr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("RECEIVED refreshCount: %d %s %s %s\n", nr.RefreshCount, nr.DbQueryToRun, nr.Requestid, time.Now().String()[:24])
        requests <- nr
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        throttlerCtx := context.Background()
        throttler := rate.NewLimiter(25, 10)

        for request := range requests { // processing each request
            wg.Add(1)
            err := throttler.Wait(throttlerCtx) // prevents db being spammed
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            go func(request NewRequest) {
                callDatabase(request) // HOW DO I CANCEL THESE THAT ARE SPAWNED IF NEW ONE ADDED TO THE CHANNEL?
                wg.Done()
            }(request)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    runtime.Goexit()
}

func callDatabase(inboundRequest NewRequest) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * (time.Duration(rand.Float64() * 2))) // simulate db doing something
    fmt.Printf("PROCESSED refreshCount: %d %s %s %s\n", inboundRequest.RefreshCount, inboundRequest.DbQueryToRun, inboundRequest.Requestid, time.Now().String()[:24])
}
```

If anyone is interested, here's the test program to generate the requests and simulate the user spamming refresh:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"

    "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)

var (
    natsURL           = "localhost:4242"
    subject           = "listen.to.refresher"
    numberRefreshes   = 10
    dashboardElements = 6
)

type NewRequest struct {
    Requestid    string `json: "requestid"`
    DbQueryToRun string `json: "dbQueryToRun"`
    Userid       int    `json: "userid"`
    RefreshCount int    `json: "refreshCount"`
}

func main() {

    nc, err := nats.Connect(natsURL)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var requests []NewRequest
    for i := 1; i <= dashboardElements; i++ {

        ints := 100 + rand.Intn(99999-10000)
        requestId := fmt.Sprintf("id_%d%s", ints, time.Now().String()[43:])
        dbToQueryRun := fmt.Sprintf("query%d", i)

        request := NewRequest{
            Requestid:    requestId,
            DbQueryToRun: dbToQueryRun,
            Userid:       1234,
            RefreshCount: i,
        }

        requests = append(requests, request)
    }

    for r := 1; r <= numberRefreshes; r++ {
        fmt.Printf(" %d REFRESH\n", r)
        for _, request := range requests {
            json, err := json.Marshal(request)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            err = nc.Publish(subject, json)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("       SENT REQUEST %s %s\n", request.Requestid, time.Now().String()[:24])
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1 / 2) // half a second between refreshes
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the way I fixed this issue was by implementing it in a different way, basically refreshing the page would show waiting until the results are back from the previous call, which would be cached, and if refreshed again would be shown instantaneously. It looks too different to what you have, but you get the idea.

Comment: Is implementing in the way I'm looking to do a bad idea? I don't have the ability to change my frontend but can ask doing that be prioritised

Comment: If a single user spamming requests (not even in a sophisticated manner, i.e. just pressing F5 a lot) can bring your site down, then so can a moderate amount of normal users. I'd prioritize adding things such as memcached which can help with both scenarios, rather than just with one of them. Regardless, to answer your question, you would have to implement some form of cancellation for the go routine, preferably using `context.Context` from Go's standard library.

Comment: I'm using an exaggerated example. With the context, how would I call cancellation? The part I'm confused with is how to check if the entry to a channel is a new version of an already running routine, and if so, cancel the already running one

Comment: Rate limiting is best accomplished at a layer in front of the app.  Why?  For one reason, once the app has to figure out whom to filter, it's already handling requests.  Secondly, the problem of DOS protection is pretty complicated to try to effectively implement at your own layer.   cloud tools, a proxy like CloudFlare, or simply linux OS layer, are good ways to approach this problem